# Why am I getting the last element of the list?

Tags: c#, json, api, class

Here is the GET REQUEST

```
var destname = textBox1.Text;
var client1 = new RestClient("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/autosuggest/v1.0/UK/GBP/en-GB/?query=" + destname);
var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request1.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "");
request1.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
IRestResponse response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DestinationName>(response1.Content);
```

And here is the classes

```
  public partial class Place1
{
    public string PlaceId { get; set; }
    public string PlaceName { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
    public string CityId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}

public partial class DestinationName
{
  public List<Place1> Places { get; set; }
}
```

When I do what is below I should be getting ES-sky which is the first element of the list but for some reason it gives me the last element of the list.

```
foreach (var a in results.Places)
{
  label1.Text = a.PlaceId;
}
```

Here is the list

```
ES-sky
BCN-sky
ALC-sky
AGP-sky
MAD-sky
PMI-sky
IBZ-sky
TENE-sky
TFS-sky
TFN-sky
```

How would I adapt the code so that my output is ES-sky and not TFN-sky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through the list, every time its writing value to "label1.Text". Use SingleOrDefault()/FirstOrDefault(). Dont use foreach loop.

Example:

var firstValue=results.Places.FirstOrDefault();
label1.Text = firstValue.PlaceId;

Comment: Absolute Legend , Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you, If you feel so please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through the loop here:

```
foreach (var a in results.Places)
{
  label1.Text = a.PlaceId;
}
```

Just get the first value with appropriate validation:

```
if(results.Places != null && results.Places.Any())
{
  var result = results.Places.First();
  label1.Text = a.PlaceId;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it can be slightly simpler than this: `if (results.Places?.FirstOrDefault() is Place place) { label1.Text = place.PlaceId; }`.

Answer (score -1):

You can bind only first place data in  list from server side and get it on client side OR
bind FirstorDefault method to get first place data from list in client side.